# error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

**I'm Building a NEXT js app and I got this error ....**

And also I used styled-component and imported that file to my responsive card file.

`error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

**and this warning also...**

`Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

**Please help me to fix this**

***This is my Responsive Card Layout file...***

```
import React from 'react';
import { GridContainer, LayoutWrapper, GridRow, GridColumn, Card, CardNumber, CardTitle, CardDescription} from '../styles/NCard.styled'

export default function Ncard  () {
    return (
    <>
      <LayoutWrapper>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridRow>
            <GridColumn sm='6' lg='4'>
              <Card >
              
                  <CardNumber>1.</CardNumber>

                  <CardTitle>Card</CardTitle>
            

           
                  <CardDescription>Rand's stated goal for writing the novel was "to show how desperately the world needs prime movers and how viciously it treats them" and to portray "what happens to the world without them".</CardDescription>
             
              </Card>
            </GridColumn>

            <GridColumn sm='6' lg='4'>
              <Card >
               
                  <CardNumber>2.</CardNumber>

                  <CardTitle>Card</CardTitle>
              

               
                  <CardDescription>The core idea for the book came to her after a 1943 telephone conversation with a friend, who asserted that Rand owed it to her readers to write fiction about her philosophy.</CardDescription>
               
              </Card>
            </GridColumn>

            <GridColumn sm='6' lg='4'>
              <Card >
             
                  <CardNumber>3.</CardNumber>

                  <CardTitle>Card</CardTitle>
              

             
                  <CardDescription>To produce Atlas Shrugged, Rand conducted research on the American railroad industry. Her previous work on a proposed (but never realized) screenplay.</CardDescription>
               
              </Card>
            </GridColumn>

            <GridColumn sm='6' lg='4'>
              <Card >
            
                  <CardNumber>4.</CardNumber>

                  <CardTitle>Card</CardTitle>
              

           
                  <CardDescription>Atlas Shrugged is set in a dystopian United States at an unspecified time, in which the country has a "National Legislature" instead of Congress and a "Head of State" instead of a President.</CardDescription>
               
              </Card>
            </GridColumn>
          </GridRow>
        </GridContainer>
      </LayoutWrapper>
      </>
    )
  
}
```

***This is Its Styled component file....***

```
import styled from "styled-components";

// Helper function to convert pixels to rems
const remy = (px) => `${px / 16}rem`;

// Function for calculating value for width
const getWidth = (value) => {
  if (!value) return;

  let width = (value / 12) * 100;
  return `width: ${width}%;`;
};

// Function for calculating value for flex
const getFlex = (value) => {
  if (!value) return;

  let flex = (value / 12) * 100;
  return `flex: 0 0 ${flex}%;`;
};

const LayoutWrapper = styled.div`
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;

  // Fix for applying proper box-sizing
  html:not(&) {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
  }

  body:not(&) {
    font: 16px / 1.618 Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
`;

// Grid container
const GridContainer = styled.div`
  padding-right: ${remy(15)};
  padding-left: ${remy(15)};
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;

  // Breakpoint for tablets
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    max-width: ${remy(540)};
  }

  // Breakpoint for small desktops
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    max-width: ${remy(720)};
  }

  // Breakpoint for medium desktops
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    max-width: ${remy(9600)};
  }

  // Breakpoint for large desktops and HD devices
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    max-width: ${remy(1140)};
  }
`;

// Grid row
const GridRow = styled.div`
  margin-right: ${remy(-15)};
  margin-left: ${remy(-15)};
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

// Grid columns
const GridColumn = styled.div`
  padding-right: ${remy(15)};
  padding-left: ${remy(15)};

  // Columns for mobile
  ${({ xs }) => (xs ? getFlex(xs) : "flex: 0 0 100%")};
  ${({ xs }) => (xs ? getWidth(xs) : "width: 100%")};

  // Columns for tablets
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    ${({ sm }) => sm && getFlex(sm)};
    ${({ sm }) => sm && getWidth(sm)};
  }

  // Columns for small desktops
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    ${({ md }) => md && getFlex(md)};
    ${({ md }) => md && getWidth(md)};
  }

  // Columns for medium desktops
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    ${({ lg }) => lg && getFlex(lg)};
    ${({ lg }) => lg && getWidth(lg)};
  }

  // Columns for large desktops and HD devices
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    ${({ xl }) => xl && getFlex(xl)};
    ${({ xl }) => xl && getWidth(xl)};
  }
`;

// Flipping card
const Card = styled.article`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: ${remy(380)};
  cursor: pointer;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;

  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 ${remy(40)} rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  }

  &.flipped {
    & > div:first-of-type { // Front side of the card
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    & > div:last-of-type { // Back side of the card
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
  }
`;

// Card content
const CardNumber = styled.span`
  display: block;
  font-size: ${remy(24)};
`;

const CardTitle = styled.h2`
  font-size: ${remy(21)};
`;

const CardDescription = styled.span`
  font-size: ${remy(16)};
`;
```

I don't know why this is not compiled please help me...

Comment: Did you export the `Ncard`? as `export default Ncard;`

Comment: yes, for the index.js file in my Next js app

Comment: I change the code , My code has `default`

Answer (score 0):

I have not exported the styles in the styled-component file.
Ex :

I think you likely forgot to export your component from your styled files, i see lot of const LayoutWrapper etc try adding export const LayoutWrapper