# Next.js Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a Next.js project and I get the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

When trying to import Layout component into my _app.js, but got the above error.

**_app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "@/components";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

**Layout.jsx**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";

import { Navbar } from "./Navbar";
import { Footer } from "./Footer";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Head>
        <title>Ecommerce Store</title>
      </Head>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <main className="main-container">empty</main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

**index.js** - I created this single file to export all components

```
export { default as Footer } from "./Footer";
export { default as Layout } from "./Layout";
export { default as Navbar } from "./Navbar";
export { default as Product } from "./Product";
export { default as HeroBanner } from "./HeroBanner";
export { default as FooterBanner } from "./FooterBanner";
export { default as Cart } from "./Cart";
```

Components folder structure
[image]

I found similar solutions for this. But none of that helped.
[(React) Element type is invalid, expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-element-type-is-invalid-expected-string-but-got)
[Next Js Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211200/next-js-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-componen)

Comment: what the structure of your component folder looks like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the layout component, import Navbar and Footer with curly braces.
When we aren't exporting a component as a default export and trying to import it as a named import (wrapped in curly braces) or vice versa because this is a common cause of the error.
Importing from a file that is located in the same directory.
If we need to import from one directory up, we would do:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";

import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Head>
        <title>Ecommerce Store</title>
      </Head>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <main className="main-container">empty</main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, I think you forgot to export a component somewhere. I see that you are exporting Layout correctly. Are you doing the same in the Navbar and Footer components?

Comment: Still I do nothing In the Navbar and Footer component. In the Layout component I use Navbar and Footer component.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you have in the Navbar and Footer files?

Comment: I just found the solution and posted an answer. so, thank you for your valuable time to answering my question. : )